# System.NullReferenceException On WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having quite a difficulty trying to trace this bug. At first I thought it was linq SQL data that's causing NRE because every time I look at the tracer log, it gives me the .cs line 37 which is pointed to my sql (stored proc) call. The reason I suspect this, the result of this sproc is null (not NULL) but there's no row return for all the fields. What I did was to put data on it, and now comes the frustration; I still get the same error. Maybe it's worth mentioning that when I use the WCF as reference(not servicereferences) a DLL straight to bin then it works perfect, only when I try to use the client (mywebservice.client) one.

Any ideas where I should be looking? It is on app.config? Also, I'm using a console app to access the WCF.

This is my code:

```
public static List<usp_GetPaymentsResult> GetScheduledPayment(DateTime DateRun, int Fee)
    {
        try
        {

            PaymentDataContext DBContext = new PaymentDataContext();
            return DBContext.usp_GetPayments(DateRun, Fee).ToList(); //line 37
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should try looking at line 37 of the cs file. If you include code here, it's possible you might receive help with the actual error.

Comment: Does `DBContext.usp_GetPayments(DateRun, Fee)` return anything? If it returns null, running a `ToList()` on it results in a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: at first it does, so I thought that was the culprit, and then I put some data in to test, still giving me same error. -thanks

Comment: ok, granting it's that one, how do you normally trap that NRE ? i tried this if(result.any()) then {return with data} else { return null} and didn't work

Answer (score 2):

```
public static List<usp_GetPaymentsResult> GetScheduledPayment(DateTime DateRun, int Fee)
{
   using(var context = new PaymentDataContext())
   {
       var payments = DBContext.usp_GetPayments(DateRun, Fee);

       if (payments == null)
       {
          // bad database! handle error here
       } 

       return payments.ToList();
   }
}
```

Please note the following:

- A DBContext is `IDisposable`. Put it in a `using` block, or it will
  not be disposed in a timely fashion.
- Your exception handling blocks did nothing but trash the exception.
  If you want to rethrow an exception, use `throw;` without the
  variable. It will rethrow the exception. Using the variable ex again
  will overwrite it's stacktrace and valuable information will be lost.
  However, as your blocks would have been nothing but rethrowing an
  exception, you can just not catch it. Same result.
- Check the result for `null` before you call an extention method like
  `.ToList()` on it.

Finally, WCF Webservices are not magic. You can put breakpoints there and debug them. If you have problems doing so, maybe it would be a good idea to ask a question about that with more details about your webservice setup (VS internal or IIS Express or IIS?) and your project structure. Guessing the error based on line number is so 80s :)

Comment: For those who found this question, one thing I found that maybe helpful that's easily to be ignored but pretty obvious is the ConnectionString, when you deploy your WCF make sure that you're local settings (connectionstring on config file) matches your sandbox on the server. Thanks for all that responded and helped.

Answer (score 0):

After a frustrating 30 mins trying to debug a WCF NullReferenceException, turned out I had corrected an error in the WCF method structure, but hadn't refreshed the service in the calling client.